# Browser change HTML code when using an "a" tag in an other

Tags: html, browser

I tried to make the first "a" tag the parent of everything, like this :

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="parents-of-every-thing">
    <h3>title</h3>
    <div>
        <a href="https://github.com/">
            <p>text</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</a>
```

but each time I tried, the browser change the code and it ended up like this :

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="parents-of-every-thing">
    <h3>title</h3>
</a>
<div>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="parents-of-every-thing"></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/">
        <p>text</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

the main problem is that the first "a" tag goes to stackoverflow.com and the second one goes to github.com ... so I'm obligated to keep the "a" tag inside another "a". What should I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An `<a>` tag can contain any other elements but another `<a>` tag. Why do you want an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Questions shouldn't contain follow up questions. They should be asked in the comment section.

Comment: I wanted to help but don't have enough reputation to comment ://

Comment: Might want to leave it to what you answered without the follow up questions then :)